# Ruby: One encoded data to another encoded csv with many lines?

Tags: ruby, csv, encoding

How to output and convert encoding?

Input: data object on UTF-8

Output: CSV on CP932(not specific cp932, the point is the data includes undefined string in 'to encoding')

```
# coding: utf-8
# input values with utf-8
# output csv with cp932
require 'csv'
headers = %w|sa sa ta tsu|
bodys = []
bodys << ["ka", "ra", "揚げ", "\u00A0"] # \u00a0 is valid in UTF-8, is undef in cp932
bodys << [1000, "1", nil, "\u00A0"]

path_to_file = './file.csv'
CSV.open(path_to_file, 'w:cp932') do |csv|
  csv << headers
  bodys.each do |values|
    csv << values
  end
end
```

## temporary solution

```
CSV.open(path_to_file, 'w:cp932') do |csv|
  csv << headers
  bodys.each do |values|
    csv << values.map {|v| v.instance_of?(String) ?
                       v.encode('cp932', 'utf-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: ' ') :
                       v }
  end
end
```

**END**

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+00A0 from UTF-8 to Windows-31J
from /Users/sane/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1736:in `write'
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0dev (2013-01-07 trunk 38733) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+00A0 from UTF-8 to Windows-31J
from /Users/sane/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1788:in `write'
```

Comment: so it is working with your temporary solution?

Comment: @phoet yes, but I think I use convert only io boundary, this case not 'before <<' but 'exactly <<' timing.